# Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.5.3 Network doesnot support

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, etherjs, nextjs

Hello I wrote a smart contract for crowd funding Actually I have two contracts One is create a campaign for donate funds and second is created campigns for crowd-funding and store all the campaigns address in one place when the user will create the campaign. Now When I try to pass the stored campaign addresses as an endpoints in params in getStaticPaths.To filter the data in next js this error is coming `Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,` version=providers/5.5.3 Network doesnot support  can anybody tell me why this error is coming?

Here is my Smart Contracts Code

```
    contract campaignFactory{

Here is my address stored

    address [] public deployedCampaigns;
    event createdCampaign(
        address indexed owner,
        string indexed category, 
        uint indexed timestamp,
        string title, 
        string storyUrI,
        uint requireAmount,
        string imageUrI,
        address campaignAddress
        );
    function createCampaign(
        string memory title,
        string memory storyUrI,
        uint requireAmount,
        string memory category,
        string memory imageUrI
    )public{
    Campaign newCampaign=new Campaign(title,storyUrI,requireAmount,msg.sender,imageUrI);
    deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));
    emit createdCampaign(msg.sender, category, block.timestamp, title, storyUrI, requireAmount, imageUrI,address(newCampaign));
    }
    this is my other smart contract to creat campaigns and donate function to send amount to owner who deployed campaigns.
    
    contract Campaign{
    event donated(address indexed owner,uint indexed amount,uint indexed timestamp);
    string public campaignTitle;
    string public story;
    uint public requireAmount;
    uint public receivedAmount;
    address payable public campaignOwner;
    string public image;
    constructor(
        string memory _campaignTitle,
        string memory _story,
        uint _requireAmount,
        address _owner,
        string memory _image
    ){
     campaignTitle=_campaignTitle;
            story=_story;
            requireAmount=_requireAmount;
            campaignOwner=payable(_owner);
            image=_image;
    }
    function donate()payable public{
    require(requireAmount>receivedAmount,"Require Amount is fullfilled");
    campaignOwner.transfer(msg.value);
    receivedAmount+=msg.value;
    emit donated(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
    }
    }
```

Here is my Next Js Code

````
export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
        AlchemyProvider
    );
    const contract=new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    CampaignFactory.abi,
    provider
    )
    const getAllCampaigns=contract.filters.createdCampaign();
    const allCampaigns=await contract.queryFilter(getAllCampaigns);
    return{
    paths:allCampaigns.map((e)=>({
    params:{```
    **The Problem is coming here**
    **address:e.args.campaignAddress.toString()**
    }
    })),
    fallback:true
    }
    };
````

Answer (score 0):

The error message you encountered suggests that the address you provided is invalid. This could happen if there are unintended characters such as spaces or numbers included in the address. In your case, it seems that the smart contract address you used is invalid.

Refer to this post: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1289